# Why isnt 2 getElementById or getElementsByClassName working?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to assign 2 commands in 1 functions and 2 `getElementsByClassName` and 2 `getElementById` didn't work but when i tried 1 of both types, it worked for some reasons. Can anyone tell me what did i do wrong here?

Working version:

```
var i=1;

function change() 
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("money")[0].innerHTML = (i++) + " $";
    document.getElementById("dolla").style.color = "green";
}
```

Not working:

```
var i=1;

    function change() 
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName("money")[0].innerHTML = (i++) + " $";
        document.getElementsByClassName("money").style.color = "green";
    }
```

Same goes:

```
var i=1;

function change() 
{
    document.getElementById("dolla")[0].innerHTML = (i++) + " $";
    document.getElementById("dolla").style.color = "green";
}
```

During the time when i use 2 getElementsByClassName/getElementById, when i assigned the `document.getElementById("dolla")/getElementsByClassName("money")` as a variable (x) but then `x.style.color = "green";` didnt work, i got an error when typing in the console, saying it was "undefined".

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>$ Button</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1>Click the button!</h1>
            </header>
            <article>
                <button type="button" onClick="change()">Click Here!</button>
                <h3>You currently have:<h3>
                <p></p>
                <b id="dolla" class="money" style="color:red">0 $</b>
                <script src="main.js"></script>
            </article>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> Returns **an array-like object** of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

We access elements of that *array-like object* by appending an index selector in square brackets.

That's why

```
document.getElementsByClassName("money")[0].innerHTML = (i++) + " $";
```

works, whilst

```
document.getElementsByClassName("money").style.color = "green";
```

doesn't.

We cannot apply `style` to an *array-like object* of elements.

### [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

> Returns a reference to **the element** by its ID; the ID is a string which can be used to uniquely identify the element, found in the HTML id attribute.

Which is why

```
document.getElementById("dolla").style.color = "green";
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/y7zjh4s5/

```js
// Access using Class
var i=1;

changeWithClass = function() 
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("money")[0].innerHTML = (i++) + " $";
    document.getElementsByClassName("money")[0].style.color = "green";
}


// Access using ID
var i=1;

changeWithID = function() 
{
    document.getElementById("dolla").innerHTML = (i++) + " $";
    document.getElementById("dolla").style.color = "blue";
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Click the button!</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
        <button type="button" onClick="changeWithClass()">Click Here (Using Class)!</button>
        <button type="button" onClick="changeWithID()">Click Here (Using ID)!</button>
        <h3>You currently have:<h3>
        <p></p>
        <b id="dolla" class="money" style="color:red">0 $</b>
    </article>
</div>
```

Solution for **getElementsByClass**

Code should be
    var i=1;

```
function change() 
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("money")[0].innerHTML = (i++) + " $";
    document.getElementsByClassName("money")[0].style.color = "green";
}
```

Since getElementsById returns an array of elements which has same class for accessing any element you need to access it using index value.

Solution for **getElementById**

```
var i=1;

function change() 
{
    document.getElementById("dolla").innerHTML = (i++) + " $";
    document.getElementById("dolla").style.color = "green";
}
```

Since **ID** is unique, so it returns an element. You can access an element directly.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
While changing color also you need to use the "getElementsByClassName("money")[0]"    
var i=1;

    function change() 
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName("money")[0].innerHTML = (i++) + " $";
        document.getElementsByClassName("money")[0].style.color = "green";
    }


For ID we do n't need [0]

var i=1;

function change() 
{
    document.getElementById("dolla").innerHTML = (i++) + " $";
    document.getElementById("dolla").style.color = "green";
}
```